# CSV to database import script

Tags: php, mysql

The default phpmyadmin functionality to import a CSV isn't working for me (spins and spins no errors) so I wrote a script to import it. I am not getting any errors from my script but none of the rows are importing! Can you see what I may be doing wrong?

```
<?php

$db_host        = 'secret';
$db_user        = 'secret';
$db_pass        = 'secret';
$db_database    = 'secret'; 

/* End config */



$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
echo "Successfully connected \n";
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

//get the csv file
   // $file = $_FILES[csv][dc.csv];
$handle = fopen("dc.csv","r");
$counter = 0;    
$data = array();






    echo "starting import \n";
    while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $data[] = $line;


        //if ($data[0]) {
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO private_schools (school_name,
                                                      city,
                                                      state,
                                                      county_code,
                                                      zip_code,
                                                      NA2,
                                                      low_grade,
                                                      high_grade,
                                                      NA3,
                                                      NA4,
                                                      NA5,
                                                      grade_range,
                                                      NA6,
                                                      NA7,
                                                      NA8,
                                                      NA9,
                                                      NA10,
                                                      NA11,
                                                      NA12,
                                                      NA13,
                                                      NA14,
                                                      NA15,
                                                      NA16) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][10])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][11])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][12])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][13])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][14])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][15])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][16])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][17])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][18])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][19])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][20])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][21])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][22])."'
                )
            " or die("THere was an issue!!: " . mysql_error()));
            //print($data[$counter][0]);
            print "INSERT INTO private_schools (school_name,
                                                      city,
                                                      state,
                                                      county_code,
                                                      zip_code,
                                                      NA2,
                                                      low_grade,
                                                      high_grade,
                                                      NA3,
                                                      NA4,
                                                      NA5,
                                                      grade_range,
                                                      NA6,
                                                      NA7,
                                                      NA8,
                                                      NA9,
                                                      NA10,
                                                      NA11,
                                                      NA12,
                                                      NA13,
                                                      NA14,
                                                      NA15,
                                                      NA16) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][10])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][11])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][12])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][13])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][14])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][15])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][16])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][17])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][18])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][19])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][20])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][21])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[$counter][22])."'
                )
            " ;
            $counter ++;
            if ($counter === 3){
            exit();
            }
       // }
    }

//var_dump($data);
?>
```

Printing the sql statement yields

> INSERT INTO private_schools (school_name, city, state, county_code,
>   zip_code, NA2, low_grade, high_grade, NA3, NA4, NA5, grade_range, NA6,
>   NA7, NA8, NA9, NA10, NA11, NA12, NA13, NA14, NA15, NA16) VALUES (
>   'Evangel Classical Christian School', 'Alabaster', 'AL', '1117',
>   '35007', '21', 'KG', '12', '5', '2', '8', 'K-12', '295', '40.7',
>   '28.8', '10.2', '99', '0.7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.3' )

Sample of CSV file:

```
Abbeville Christian Academy,Abbeville,AL,1067,36310,42,PK,12,6,2,8,K-12,157,52.9,16.6,9.5,95.5,0.6,0,1.9,0,0.6,1.3
Kingwood Christian School,Alabaster,AL,1117,35007,21,KG,12,6,2,4,K-12,413,44.1,33.1,12.5,88.9,6.8,0,1.9,0,0.2,2.2
Evangel Classical Christian School,Alabaster,AL,1117,35007,21,KG,12,5,2,8,K-12,295,40.7,28.8,10.2,99,0.7,0,0,0,0,0.3
Westwood Bapt Weekday Edu Ministry,Alabaster,AL,1117,35007,21,PK,KG,6,2,5,K-6,12,50,1,12,100,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it at all? There are 141 lines there to check. You can surely narrow it down further?

Comment: Make sure fgetcsv is properly detecting line endings. There is a flag you set for that

Comment: fixed a bug on commit

Comment: If the CSV file is on the server, MySQL could (very probably) import it using the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension as mysql is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Manpage for  [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) says

> To escape database parameters, DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_literal(), pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL) should be used for security reasons.

For mysql try [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), and for mysqli try [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

I don't use this format to check/display errors, but I think the way you would write this is:

```
mysql_query($yourInsertQueryString) or die("THere was an issue!!: " . mysql_error());
```

Are all of those column types really strings?

Comment: Column types in the database range... there's text, varchar, int, floats... is my insert format not correct for that? should the numbers not have quotes around them?

Comment: Correct, they should not. `string_type_column = 'value', number_type_column = 123`

Comment: Ahhh that would make sense. I'll update you later. I have to work on some other things.

Comment: @CaitlinHavener and you tried changing the `mysql_query() or die()` statement? Still no error?

Comment: Hmmm... didn't realize putting the query itself in there would cause issues. Tried the statement exactly as you said and finally got some hints.. after debugging with those hints for a while I finally did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach too, quoting the fields too and using the "coupple" assingment to verify the correct assignment (a frequent problem with csv importing)

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'secret';
$db_user        = 'secret';
$db_pass        = 'secret';
$db_database    = 'secret'; 

$_db = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_database,$_db);

$fileds = array(

"school_name",
"city",
"state",
"county_code",
"zip_code",
"NA2",
"low_grade",
"high_grade",
"NA3",
"NA4",
"NA5",
"grade_range",
"NA6",
"NA7",
"NA8",
"NA9",
"NA10",
"NA11",
"NA12",
"NA13",
"NA14",
"NA15",   
"NA16",
);

$handle = fopen("dc.csv","r");
$counter = 0;
$data = array();
echo "starting import \n";
while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $data[] = $line;
}
foreach($data as $row){
    if(count($fileds) != count($row)){
        continue;
    }
    $couples = array();
    foreach($fileds as $k => $v){
        $couples[] = sprintf("`%s` = '%s",$v ,mysql_real_escape_string($row[$k],$_db));
    }
    $_sql = 'INSERT INTO private_schools '.join(',', $couples).';';
    echo "$_sql\n";
    mysql_query($_sql);

}
// and remeber to commit if you use a transactiona storage engine
mysql_query('commit',$_db); // fixed for "old" client
```

Comment: Very strange, it'a a *working* example! Well, you found a a solution, but it's more nicely say: "don't work, it give me this error: bla bla"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mysqlimport. You run in from a command window.

[Heres a nice easy tutorial](http://chriseiffel.com/everything-linux/how-to-import-a-large-csv-file-to-mysql/)

It does not matter if you are using windows, it is available on that as well, just the same.